# Combine the result set from both tables based on inno

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table1 with following structure and data:

```
header  type agrid inno stallno
0       D     14    001  000
0       D     14    008  000
0       N     14    008  000
```

Another table with following structure and data:

```
header  type  agrid inno stallno
1        NULL  14    001  000
1        NULL  14    008  000
```

How can I achieve the below result set: I tried `row_number` it works for couple of data sets it doesn't work for other

```
header  type  agrid  inno
0       D      14     001
1       NULL   14     001
0       D      14     008
1       NULL   14     008
0       N      14     008
1       NULL   14     008
```

I tried `row_number` but worked only for couple of agrid's and didn't work for other.

Comment: 1) please explain the logic behind how the results are obtained. 2) Please show us your attempt even if it didn't work.

Comment: I combined two tables result into cte, adding a row_no over (partiiton by agrid,inno,header order by agrid,inno,header ).    Again did a row_number() over (partition by row_no,aggrid, inno order by row_no,aggrid, inno) from cte order by aggrid

Comment: 1) Add any clarifications into the question. 2) That still doesn't explain the logic behind how you want the rows combined.

Comment: For every header 0 i want a corresponding trailer 1 to show in the final result set

Comment: As I already said [edit] any clarifications into your question. And please define what "corresponding" means, I guess you are matching them on some criteria, which you don't explain.

Comment: I am sorry, its based on inno

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to build two queries, one for table 1 and one for table 2, then union them together using the `row_number` and the header value to order them.

```
create table table1 (header bit, [type] char(1), agrid int, inno int, stallno int);
create table table2 (header bit, [type] char(1), agrid int, inno int, stallno int);

insert into table1 (header, [type], agrid, inno, stallno)
values
(0, 'D', 14, 001, 000),
(0, 'D', 14, 008, 000),
(0, 'N', 14, 008, 000);

insert into table2 (header, [type], agrid, inno, stallno)
values
(1, null, 14, 001, 000),
(1, null, 14, 008, 000);
 
select t1.*, row_number() over (order by t1.type, t1.inno) rn
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.*, row_number() over (order by t1.type, t1.inno) rn
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.inno = t1.inno
order by rn, header;
```

Returns

| header | type | agrid | inno | stallno | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | D | 14 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | *null* | 14 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | D | 14 | 8 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | *null* | 14 | 8 | 0 | 2 |
| 0 | N | 14 | 8 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | *null* | 14 | 8 | 0 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FxoiF-Os)

Note: For future reference, please take the time to ensure your question is clear and easy to understand. And please create the DDL+DML (as I have shown here) so that people who wish to answer don't have to type your sample data in.

Comment: Sorry and Thank you, I will check now

Comment: @CVV how did you get on?

Comment: It worked for couple of ID's , but not for other. I will create the sample data soon and post it. Thanks for your help

Comment: @cvv since this answers the question you asked you can consider accepting it and then ask a new question. Please do not update this question since it has already been answered.